# Read Text file as payload in Rest Assured using java

Tags: java, rest-assured

I need to read the payload from the text file in Rest Assured using java. 
The payload will be like

```
{     
     "country": "India"

        }
```

Comment: "read the payload from the text file in Rest Assured" what do you mean? Using a text file's content as a payload for a request?

Comment: Yes, please share code if u have and I am trying to write this code.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're having. Reading from a file? Creating a post request with a body? Putting it all together? Please, be precise.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not precise ,however kindly see the below code .
Using it you can pass a json payload from .json file .(Insstead .txt use .json)

```
@Test(enabled=true,priority=1,description="Use Json file for Rest assured paylord")
    public void useJsonfileForRestassuredpayload() throws IOException {     
          String jsonBody = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(".\\resources\\CreateUser.json")));        
        RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost:3000/";
        given().contentType("application/json").
        body(jsonBody).when().post("posts/").then().assertThat().statusCode(201).log().all();                    

    }
```